# SQL Query to select row in db who's publish time and end time should not overlap

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using codeignitor and i have to publish a question one at time. For every question i have a publish date, publish time and end date, end time. So, it will be like "We have to publish question X on 28th September 9:00 PM till 2nd Oct 11:00 AM". The date and time for both start and end are stored in separate columns.

Therefore, for every question i have 4 columns as publish_date, publish_time, end_date and end_time.

Now i want to run a query to check if there is a row in database for the selected time period and if not i can create a new question on that time frame. The quesy i tried is:

```
$query_check = $this->db->query("... (see query below) ...");
```

SQL Query is the following :

```
SELECT question_id 
FROM questions 
WHERE 
(
    publish_date < '".$publish_date."' 
    AND 
    end_date > '".$publish_date."' 
    AND question_id NOT in (".$question_id.")
) 
OR 
(
    publish_date < '".$end_date."' 
    AND end_date > '".$end_date."' 
    AND question_id NOT in (".$question_id.")
) 
OR 
(
    publish_date > '".$publish_date."' 
    AND 
    publish_date < '".$end_date."' 
    AND 
    question_id NOT in (".$question_id.")
) 
OR 
(
    end_date > '".$publish_date."' 
    AND 
    end_date < '".$end_date."' 
    AND question_id NOT in (".$question_id.")
)  
OR 
(
    '".$publish_date."' = publish_date 
    AND 
    '".$publish_time."' >= publish_time 
    AND 
    '".$publish_time."' < end_time 
    AND question_id NOT in (".$question_id.")
) 
OR 
(
    '".$publish_date."' = end_date 
    AND 
    '".$publish_time."' < end_time 
    AND 
    '".$publish_time."' >= publish_time 
    AND question_id NOT in (".$question_id.")
) 
OR 
(
    '".$end_date."' = publish_date 
    AND 
    '".$end_time."' > publish_time 
    AND 
    '".$end_time."' <= end_time 
    AND 
    question_id NOT in (".$question_id.")
) 
OR
(
    '".$end_date."' = end_date 
    AND 
    '".$end_time."' <= end_time 
    AND 
    '".$end_time."' > publish_time 
    AND question_id NOT in (".$question_id.")
)
```

I am missing many scenarios in it. As if a ques A is from 28 Sep 2:00PM to 29 Sep 2:00PM , i can still create a new ques B for time period 27 Sep 2:00PM to 29 Sep 3:00PM. This should not happen as ques A comes inside the time period of question B. So ideally above query should return 0 rows.

Can any one help me in this. Any idea or help will be highly appricated

Comment: using between would reduce the `OR` ing of the query

Comment: can you post sample data or create a SQL fiddle?

Comment: I guess you need `AND` ing check this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52c87/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the BETWEEN clause?

```
SELECT question_id FROM questions
where '".$publish_date."' BETWEEN publish_date AND end_date
AND '".$publish_time." BETWEEN publish_time AND end_time
```

Comment: What about a time period starting Sep 28 11am and ending Sep 29 10am? Since `'".publish_time."' BETWEEN '11:00:00' and '10:00:00'` is `FALSE` for all values of publish_time, such a row would never be selected.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is, that you want to check if the time period defined by `publish_date`, `publish_time`, `end_date`, and `end_time` overlaps with the time period of any already existing question.

A time period overlaps with another if it starts before the other ends and ends after the other started. In order to do this efficiently, you have to combine all dates and times to date-times. You can simply use string concatenation and the comparison will work correctly.

```
SELECT question_id
FROM questions
WHERE '".$publish_date." ".$publish_time."' < CONCAT(end_date, ' ', end_time)
AND '".$end_date." ".$end_time."' > CONCAT(publish_date, ' ', publish_time)
'".$publish_date." ".$publish_time."' < CONCAT(end_date, ' ', end_time)
```